# How Can i extend TabViewItem with view class for titleView instead of title?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I want like this tab bar with dynamic text instead of static. Like facbook notification badge.

So can i extend TabViewItem with view class for titleView instead of title?

```
<TabViewItem>
  <TabViewItem.titleVew> 
      <StackLayout>
      <Label text="Hello"></Label> 
      <Label text="World"></Label> 
   </StackLayout> 
 </TabViewItem.titleView>
 <TabViewItem.view> 
          <T1:tab1/> 
  </TabViewItem.view> 
</TabViewItem>
```

For reference: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently {NS} does not have this feature. It is only in

```
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar>
      <ActionBar.titleView>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
          <Label text="AppName" />
          <Image src="res://app_icon" />
        </StackLayout>
      </ActionBar.titleView>
    </ActionBar>
  </Page.actionBar>
```

TabViewItem.titleView does not have like Actionbar.titleView.

Answer (score 0):

In this current update ({N} - 2.1.1) they were added icon support for tabs for that you can use `*tabItem="{title:'',iconSource:'res://YOUR_ICON_NAME'}"` to setup tab icons.

But i guess badge count functionality is not implemented (I am not sure) at this very moment. With some research task i found some links that might be helpful for you as follows :

1) https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=badge

2) https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/71

3) https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications

4) http://www.telerik.com/forums/badge-count-is-gone-when-app-is-opened